# Convert Horizontal 1920x1080 mp4 video to Vertical 1080x1920 mp4 with Actual content size of 1080x608

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

How to convert horizontal 1920x1080 mp4 video to vertical 1080x1920 mp4 with actual content size of 1080x608

I know ffmpeg can do it, but don't know how to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the scale filter.

```
ffmpeg -i in -vf scale=1080:1920:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1080:1920:-1:-1 -c:a copy out
```

Answer (score 0):

FFmpeg does it through the video filter - [transpose](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#transpose-1); clockwise or counter-clockwise option is available.